# PHP send mail with attachment destroyed

Tags: php, email, pdf

I have a simple script in PHP and FPDI : https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/

So I manually create a PDF and after that I'm trying to send it in email :

```
        $headers = "From: xxxxxxxxxxxx <".$from.">".$eol;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
        $message = "--".$separator.$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
        $message .= $body.$eol;
        $message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
        $message .= $attachment.$eol;
        $message .= "--".$separator."--";

        // send message
        mail($to, "subject", $message, $headers);
```

When I try to send this email to my gmail account, it's ok, I receive email + pdf.

But if I try to send to a custom email and if I check on Thunderbird for example, my pdf is corrupted, and I get an error like : "This attachment is empty, please check the sender. Firewall or antivirus can destroy attachment"

Any ideas ? What's the problem ? My sender email ? My PHP script ? Other ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you're sending attachments via PHP, forget about using the `mail()` function. Use either the PHPMailer or SwiftMailer libraries -- they will make things much *much* easier. (adding an attachment becomes a single line of code rather than all that messing around with separators and content types)

Comment: You seem to be missing the second `$eol` between the attachment's headers and its content. Some clients may recognise and accept this, others will reject it as malformed. SPAM filters will almost always block it for being malformed.

Comment: That is why I always use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) - it takes care of everything.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol where exactly ?

Comment: Notice how you have two `$eol` just before `$body`, but only one before `$attachment`. There should be two there too.

Comment: Ok, it was just that... My bad :) Thanks you